# IIS - The resource you are looking for has been removed

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I have a problem for publishing a web application.
I tried to publish it in the IIS, but I have the following message:
"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
There is not http error code  like 400.x or 500.x, Just that message.
I don't know what is happening, I try to publish it like a application in the default web site and a new web site, the result is the same.

I publish web apps in others server and I don't have any problem.

My application a ASP web App.
Windows server 2012

just in case in my load I have:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

in my web config, just in case too, I have:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>    
</modules>
```

Please,,... any idea?
I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance
best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved.
The server had several application pools, 2, 2.5 etc.
besides this server has a software platform with own applications pools.
Anyway... I choosed .Net V4.5 Classic and works fine until now.

Regards